# Mid-square hashing using bit-shift

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, bitwise-operators

for school I have to implement a mid-square hash function. I understand the theory but I don't know how to use the bit-shift operator on the squared key. I searched the internet for code implementations of the above, but found none so far. The problem is stated as follows:

> Use array T with size 20 and insert the following values: { 1,5,21,26,39,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,111,145,146 }.

Your help is very appreciated. I was successful implementing this problem using division hash function with linear probing. Now I have to do it with mid-square hashing.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Method body and math function to square my key value. That's it. If I would see how to use the bit shift in the context of hashing that would be enough. Like an example to get the middle value of an integer.

Comment: First hit on Google: http://research.cs.vt.edu/AVresearch/hashing/midsquare.php  The "problem statement" you give above has nothing to do with mid-square hashing, and smells of "do my homework please".  Post the code you have already written for mid-square hash and then explain the part you're having trouble with.  ***That's*** how SO works.

Comment: Please tell me why do you think this is not a mid-square hash problem. What I asked was: "for school I have to implement a mid-square hash function. I understand the theory but I don't know how to use the **bit-shift operator** on the squared key", all I wanted is the answer _Rotten194_ provided. If this smells like "do my homework please", then I am sorry this was not my intention. Instead of judging that easily, read the question with more care. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To get the middle bits of the number, you could do:

```
(number >> 6) & 0xf;
```

`>> 6` shifts the left parameter 6 bits to the left, getting the middle four bits in the bottom four bits (for a short). `& 0xf;` then masks out the top bits, leaving only the bottom bits.

`((10 * 10 % 65536) >> 6) & 0xf == 1`